# Adobe Edge how to use correctly if / else statements in game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe, adobe-edge

I'm building a game currently but I have a small problem with keeping the score. Basically I have an textfield that gets a random word input, then if someone clicks on the field or symbol containing the field then I want to check the random word input, if it's a correct word I want to update score textfield, if it's incorrect I want to update errors textfield.

For this I am using an if/else construction, the problem I have with it is that in my game every click only goes either in the if statement or if I change code then only the else, but it's not checking symbol for symbol, every time I click to see if it's an correct word or not. Here is the code I am using on the symbol.click symbol. My question is, am I doing anything wrong in the if/else statements or are my variable calling methods wrong. I have source files on request.

---

```
symbol.click:
var y = sym.getVariable("lijst");
var x = "bommen";

// if variables are a match then update score with 1

if (sym.getVariable("x") == sym.getVariable("y"))
{var score3 = sym.getComposition().getStage().getVariable("score1"); 
score3= score3 +=1;
sym.getComposition().getStage().$ ("scoreTxt").html(score3);
sym.getComposition().getStage().setVariable("score1", score3);
}

// else update error textfield with 1

else {
var fouten= sym.getComposition().getStage().getVariable("fouten1"); 
fouten= fouten +=1;
sym.getComposition().getStage().$ ("hpTxt").html(fouten);
sym.getComposition().getStage().setVariable("fouten1", fouten);
}
```

---

```
symbol.creationComplete
var words = ['bommen',
'dammen',
'kanonnen',
'dollen',
'bomen',
'feesten',
'lampen',
'voeten',
];
var lijst = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
sym.$("dynamicText").html(lijst);
```

---

```
//And my stage: 

stage.creationComplete
// some different variables declarations

sym.setVariable("score1", 0);
sym.setVariable("fouten1", 0)
//var game = sym.getComposition().getStage();
var cirkels = [];
var test1 = "bommen";
var score2 = sym.getComposition().getStage().getVariable("score1"); 
var fouten = sym.getComposition().getStage().getVariable("fouten1");
var cirkelStart = {x:180,y:190};
var cirkelSpacing = {x:170,y:170};

function init(){    
initPlayer();   
spawnCirkels();
}

//this is for score and error updating

function initPlayer(){
sym.$("scoreTxt").html(score2);
sym.$("hpTxt").html(fouten);

}
// create symbols on a grid

function spawnCirkels(){
var cirkel;
var el; 
var i;
var xPos = cirkelStart.x;
var yPos = cirkelStart.y;
var col = 0;
for(i = 0;i < 15;i++){      
cirkel = sym.createChildSymbol("Cirkel", "Stage");
cirkel.play(Math.random() * 1000);
cirkels.push(cirkel);
el = cirkel.getSymbolElement();
el.css({"position":"absolute", "top":yPos + "px", "left":xPos + "px"});             
xPos += cirkelSpacing.x;        
col++;              
if(col === 5){
col = 0;
yPos += cirkelSpacing.y;
xPos = cirkelStart.x;
}
}   
}

init();
```

---

If anyone sees what I am doing wrong let me know!

Thanks for your help anyway!